# Easytable colors the whole table instead of item in enumerate

Tags: tables, color, enumerate, minipage, subcaption

I can't solve this weird error: I have a table (easytable) and an enumerate, which I want side by side.
In the first slide I want part of the table and the first item in color green. But the output shows the text in normal color, and in the second slide the whole table is green.

This happens with minipage and subfigure (subcaption package). When I write the table and enumerate environments separately, it doesn't happen.

What's more, I have another frame, very far from this one, which starts with a table (easytable) inside a subfigure, no color whatsoever, and it's also completely green. Is this a bug?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{easytable}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.23\textwidth}
    \begin{TAB}{|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}
      $X_3$ & $X_4$ & $X_5$  \\
      {\color<2->{red}1} & {\color<1->{green}0} &   \\
      {\color<2->{red}2} & {\color<1->{green}0} &    
    \end{TAB} 
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
      \item {{\color{green}Green text.}}
      \item {{\color{red}Red text.}}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: PDF output of the MWE shown in my question.]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. However, this is not so relevant since I do not think that this is the appropriate way of coloring texts, nor to change the color on certain overlays.

Comment: What is the appropriate way?

Comment: For instance `\alt<2->{\textcolor{red}{1}}{1}` or use `\alert<2->{1}`, you can change the alert color with e.g. `\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}`.

Comment: How is that better? The first one is more verbose (I have long sentences that need color in other places) and I'm using 3 custom colors so alert doesn't solve it. Thanks for the ideas anyway, I'm a beginner with beamer and I'm still struggling with its semantics.